# Expressions for "something's benefits manifest only under certain conditions"

Tags: expressions, terminology

I want to express "something has benefits/advantages. But they manifest only when certain conditions hold or under certain restrictions or certain prices have to be paid".

Is there any terms/expressions/sentences for this?

Comment: ["There's no such thing as a free lunch."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch) (It might not work in all instances, but you're pretty vague here, and haven't given any concrete examples to narrow the range of possible suggestions.)

Comment: Why not say *conditional benefits*?

Answer (score 2):

The main phrase that springs to mind is *if you want roses, you must have thorns*, or as [Anne Bronte](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/roses) put it:-

> “But he who dares not grasp the thorn  Should never crave the rose.”

or somewhat less poetically *you get owt for nowt unless it's for thy sins*.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily referring to your first qualification (a benefit), but a generalization of such a circumstance:

[latent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latent): present and capable of emerging or developing but not now visible, obvious, active, or symptomatic

So possibly a latent benefit.

Answer (score -1):

I would just say "potential benefits/advantages".